# Commerce 1 get customer from user model

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, users

In PHP, is it possible to grab the customer model from a user model?

EDIT:
I just noticed that it is possible to attach a customer info field to the user.  How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to do that, you're just adding custom fields to the user when those can be fetched easilly.
A customer will always be a user, but a user might not be a customer.

If you intend to get the customer details from a plugin (with PHP) you can just get the customer details (if exist) from the user, by using the Commerce_CustomersService

code example would be

```
$customer = craft()->commerce_customers->getCustomerByUserId($user->id);
```

this will either return the customer model or null (if a customer is not created against the user).

Comment: That is definitely the correct answer!  Thanks!  Have you had success programmatically creating orders in Commerce 1 in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  For anyone else looking for this info, the answer is:

Create a field of type Customer Customer Info.  Add it as a field in the User Field Settings.

Access it using the handle you assigned it.

E.g.

```
$customer = $user->customerInfo;
```

Comment: Marked RoussKS as the right answer.